# Ruby Hash to array of values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this:

```
hash  = { "a"=>["a", "b", "c"], "b"=>["b", "c"] }
```

and I want to get to this: `[["a","b","c"],["b","c"]]`

This seems like it should work but it doesn't:

```
hash.each{|key,value| value}
=> {"a"=>["a", "b", "c"], "b"=>["b", "c"]}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The answers below are correct (`hash.values` being the better IMO). But I wanted to point out when you provide a block to `Hash#each` it will just return the full value of the hash. If you want to do an operation on each item and return that as an array, use `Hash#collect` or its alias `Hash#map`. More stuff on Enumerables [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

Comment: This question looks strangely familiar... I wonder how many people are working on the same homework assignment right now.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Also, a bit simpler....

```
>> hash = { "a"=>["a", "b", "c"], "b"=>["b", "c"] }
=> {"a"=>["a", "b", "c"], "b"=>["b", "c"]}
>> hash.values
=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

[Ruby doc here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values)

Comment: +! Nifty!  I will upvote despite having a competing answer (using `map`), cos I like this a lot!

Comment: `Hash#values` is not only simpler, but more efficient. Compare `time ruby -e '(1..1000000).reduce({}){|h,i| h.store i,i; h}.values'` with `time ruby -e '(1..1000000).reduce({}){|h,i| h.store i,i; h}.map{|k,v| v}'`

Comment: +1 (Dazzled amazingly after I tried your code) I spent one day with no luck removing the index using many methods... All I can say thank you very much!!! :D

Comment: Are the keys printed in the exact order which they occur ?

Answer (score 51):

I would use:

```
hash.map { |key, value| value }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but it's a more complicated equivalent to `Hash#values`.

Comment: Yes, I also upvoted Ray's answer.  I'm happy to upvote a competing answer when I like it too.

Comment: I think we are not competing here but helping each other, right? :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for when trying to create an array from a hash using it's keys as values. Thanks :)

Comment: Useful when you need to also do some logic with the *keys* at the same time.

Comment: Since you're not using the `key` variable, you can even do `hash.map { |_, value| value }`

Comment: Upvoted.  Although hash.values is a more appropriate answer to the actual question asked, this answer helped me in the problem I was googling for.

Answer (score 24):

```
hash.collect { |k, v| v }
#returns [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

[`Enumerable#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) takes a block, and returns an array of the results of running the block once on every element of the enumerable. So this code just ignores the keys and returns an array of all the values.

The `Enumerable` module is pretty awesome. Knowing it well can save you lots of time and lots of code.

Comment: Don't forget that, like @Ray Toal's answer, `hash.values` is ultimately the correct answer here.

Comment: Or `hash.map(&:second)` :)

Answer (score 12):

It is as simple as

```
hash.values
#=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

this will return a new array populated with the values from hash

if you want to store that new array do

```
array_of_values = hash.values
#=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"]]

array_of_values
 #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
hash  = { :a => ["a", "b", "c"], :b => ["b", "c"] }
hash.values #=> [["a","b","c"],["b","c"]]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12771873/revisions as you can see the formatting of your code was way off

Answer (score 3):

There is also this one:

```
hash = { foo: "bar", baz: "qux" }
hash.map(&:last) #=> ["bar", "qux"]
```

Why it works:

The `&` calls `to_proc` on the object, and passes it as a block to the method.

```
something {|i| i.foo }
something(&:foo)
```

Comment: A more in depth explanation http://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-ruby-idiom-map-with-symbol/