# How to remove outer hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Let's say I've got hash like this:

```
{"290"=>{"id"=>"290", "name"=>"Test Number", "order"=>"2"}}
```

I want to to have:

```
{"id"=>"290", "name"=>"Test Number", "order"=>"2"}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Hash to array of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560335/ruby-hash-to-array-of-values)

Comment: If that's the form of your hash (say `h`), but values may vary, then `h.values.first` or `h.to_a.first.last` will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `h = {"290"=>{"id"=>"290", "name"=>"Test Number", "order"=>"2"}}`. Now you can do `h = h["290"]` and you will have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below image: It's show different approaches to get the same result :D
[image]

Comment: Image answers it in a better way :p