# Method to check hash for values which may be a single string or an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash which contains values such as....

```
    EXAMPLE = {
      "101" => "SO01",
      "102" => "SO02",
      "103" => "SO03",
      "105" => %w(S005 SO04)
    }
```

I want to search the hash for say SO04 and get back "105", or "SO03" and get back "103".  I'm sure there is a good way to do this but it's slipping my mind currently.  I had been simply using EXAMPLE.key() but that's not going to cut it now that I realize there are arrays in there.

Comment: Mabe this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560335/ruby-hash-to-array-of-values) question could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>> EXAMPLE = {"101" => "SO01",
              "102" => "SO02",
              "103" => "SO03",
              "105" => %w(SO05 SO04)}
>> EXAMPLE.find { |_,v| Array(v).include?('SO02') }.try(:first)
=> "102"
>> EXAMPLE.find { |_,v| Array(v).include?('SO05') }.try(:first)
=> "105"
>> EXAMPLE.find { |_,v| Array(v).include?('SO06') }.try(:first)
=> nil
```

`.first` is needed on the end because `#find` returns an array of `[key, value]`.

If you are using Ruby 2.3 or later, you can use the safe navigation operator in place of `try`:

```
>> EXAMPLE.find { |_,v| Array(v).include?('SO05') }&.first
=> "105"
>> EXAMPLE.find { |_,v| Array(v).include?('SO06') }&.first
=> nil
```

Comment: awesome.  thanks a bunch.  I knew I was forgetting something simple.  I'll accept once the 5 minute wait is up.

Comment: Out of curiosity why did you choose to place the `hash_values` in an array first then `flatten` before using the `include?` method? It seems like you could just as well write `v.include?('SO05')` since both arrays and strings have the `include?` method

Comment: String#include? would return an item if the search term is a substring of any value. For example: `EXAMPLE.find { |_, v| v.include?('SO') }.first` would return `'101'`. The solution I suggested is more consistent with the #key method, which the OP was using before the array complication was introduced.

Comment: I see the logic behind your approach now. Thanks for clearing that up. Another approach could involve just using  `Array(v).include?(string)` as that way when `v` is an array it just returns that array so there won't be any array of arrays that needs to be flattened

Comment: Yes, that is a slightly better solution. I'll edit and make the change.

Comment: Getting error usign `try`:
> `NoMethodError: undefined method `try' for ["102", "SO02"]:Array`

Comment: Use the safe navigation operator (`&`) instead. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXAMPLE = {
  "101" => "SO01",
  "102" => "SO02",
  "103" => "SO03",
  "105" => ["S005", "SO04"]
}

def value_to_key(h, value)
  h.keys.find { |k| Array(h[k]).include?(value) }
end

value_to_key(EXAMPLE, "SO02") #=> "102" 
value_to_key(EXAMPLE, "SO04") #=> "105" 
value_to_key(EXAMPLE, "cat")  #=> nil
```

Note:

```
Array("SO03")           #=> ["SO03"] 
Array(["S005", "SO04"]) #=> ["S005", "SO04"]
```

An equivalent, but more memory-demanding, method is shown below. The reason for the difference in memory requirements is explained in the comments.

```
def value_to_key(h, value)
  h.keys.find { |k| [*h[k]].include?(value) }
end

[*"SO03"]           #=> ["SO03"] 
[*["S005", "SO04"]] #=> ["S005", "SO04"]
```

Comment: Why not `Array(h[k])`? It wouldn't create a new array from an existing one.

Comment: @Eric, please explain your second sentence. Readers: Eric is suggesting `Array(h[k])` in place of `[*h[k]]`, as `Array("SO03") #=> ["SO03"]` and `Array(["S005", "SO04"]) #=> ["S005", "SO04"] `.

Comment: It's my understanding that `Array(a)` returns `a` directly. `[*a]` first flattens a, and packs it again in a new array.

Comment: @Eric, so it does: `a = [1,2]; a.object_id #=> 70110799250340; Array(a).object_id #=> 70110799250340`. I'll do the edit. Thanks.